# Why is this code showing the error (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name') while I run it?

Tags: python

I don't know what this is or how this occured. When I ran this same code in ChatGPT, it said that there were no errors, so I felt this was the place to ask.

I tried writing a code in Python for creating a report card. It resulted in this error.

Error : - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'k'

Code:

```
#to print marklist with total and percentage

#essential details of the student 
r=int(input('Enter Roll No. :'))
n=int(input('Enter Name:'))
s=int(input('Enter School name :'))

#marks
eng= float(input('Enter your English marks :'))
math= float(input('Enter your Mathematics marks :'))
social=float(input('Enter your Social marks :'))
science=float(input('Enter your Science marks :'))
malayalam= float(input('Enter your Malayalam marks :'))
hindi= float(input('Enter your Hindi marks :'))

#essential calculations
t= eng+math+social+science+malayalam+hindi
p=(t*100)/480

#grade determination
if p>=80:
    grade='A1'
if p>=70:
    grade='A2'
if p>=60:
    grade='B1'
if p>=50:
    grade='B2'
if p>=40:
    grade='C1'
if p>=33:
    grade='C2'
else:
    grade='E'

#representation of earlier input
print ('Roll Number :',r)
print ('Name :',n)
print ('School Name:',s)
print ('Total:',t)
print ('Percentage :',p)
print ('Final Grade:',grade)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Fixed that, sorry

Comment: Also please add what inputs you are using. I can't imagine you want to cast school name as integer.

Comment: I cannot see the code since my company block imgur but the error in the title occurs when trying to do the following: `int('name')`. Therefore you probably are passing a viariable with contents `'name'` to the `int()` function.

Comment: sorry I'm just a beginner

Comment: @amused_turtle14, why you need name and school name as int?

Comment: @amused_turtle14 It's ok, we'll get there. It's just best practice to make the question as easy to understand as possible. For example, I'm asking what inputs you are using, since you are converting all your inputs to either `int` or `float`, however from the prompts used in `input` (e.g. 'name', 'school name'), I doubt that you want all of them converted as `int`, however in your particular case you might do (having the inputs would help decide whether it's a mistake, or a purposeful use of `int`)

Comment: i think i fixed it

* changed the int to just normal input 
* changed the many ifs into elif

Comment: Notwithstanding the issue around passing all of the first three inputs to *int()* did you notice that **all** values of *p* >= 33 will be assigned grade C2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error because of you had given the datatype as int in the field of 'name' and 'school  name'.It should be string. Try:

```py
n = input('Enter Name:')
s = input('Enter school name:')
```